# Python sdist upload hangs on upload (Windows)

Tags: distutils, python-packaging

```
setup.py sdist upload -r local --show-response
```

hangs on

```
Creating tar archive
removing 'my_lib-0.0.3' (and everything under it)
running upload
```

The first question is **how can I get more debug info on what is the problem with `running upload`?** Until that, I can't ask a more specific question on my problem. The second will be how to solve this problem and what to check.

I use Windows 10. I put `.pypirc` to `{HOME}`, `{HOME}\pip`, `{HOME}\AppData\Local\pip`, because I am not sure where it should be placed.

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
  pypi
  local

[pypi]
username:some_user
password:

[local]
repository: http://my_repo.local:9292
username:some_user
password:
```

I tried the same on another PC (with the same python environment, config, etc.) with Ubuntu and it works ok.

I also tried to use `twine`, but the effect is similar- it hangs without output.

Comment: is `my_repo.local` the same on your windows and your Ubuntu?

Comment: yes, it is the same.